# An action dispatch inside the 'then' part of a Promise is not being called (React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I fetch some data from my API, but when it gets returned, the `then` part of `getLocation()` don't get executed, and hence the dispatch isn't called, and my action `RECIEVE_SHOPS` isn't triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

```
export function receiveShops(data) {
    return { type: 'RECIEVE_SHOPS', shops: data.shops, time: Date.now() }
}

 //   http://localhost:3001/nearby?lat=30&long=-6
export function fetchShops(location) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestShops());
        console.log("--fetchShops--");
        console.log(location)
        return axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:3001/nearby',
            params: {
                lat: location.lat,
                long: location.long
            }
        })
    }
}

function getLocation() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
                resolve(pos);
            });
        } else {
            reject("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")
        }
    }
    )
}

export function loadNearbyShops() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return getLocation()
        .then(position => dispatch(getCoords(position)))
        .then(position => dispatch(fetchShops(position)))
        .then(data => dispatch(receiveShops(data)))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    };    
}

export function getCoords(position) {
    return {
        type: 'GET_LOCATION',
        long: position.coords.longitude,
        lat: position.coords.latitude
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

This is how I call `loadNearbyShops`:

```
store.dispatch(loadNearbyShops())
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are aware that `loadNearbyShops` is a curried function, right? Can you should how you call it?

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I've edited the post with how I call the curried function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on what currying is. In your function, you're returning a function, which means you have to call the function twice in order to run the inner function with the actual content.

```js
function curriedSum(a){
  return function(b) {
    console.log(a + b)
  }
}

curriedSum(10)(5)
```

Your outer function doesn't take any arguments, but your inner one does. You're passing your definition of what `dispatch` should be in the inner function. You're looking for something more along the lines of this:

```
loadNearbyShops()(store.dispatch)
```